What is this movie featuring a child prodigy?
I'm trying to think of the name of a movie from the 80's or 90's that features a child that is a prodigy of some sort but he is also socially awkward. 
I remember a scene in the movie where the child says "Corelle" and his mom asks him what he's talking about. Then, another adult enters and flips over the plate and it says Corelle on it. The kid knew what brand it was without even being able to read. 
Does this ring a bell for anyone?

We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification.  What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

Just throwing something out there. Could it be Little Man Tate (1991)?
"It tells the story of a seven-year-old child prodigy, Fred Tate (Adam Hann-Byrd), who struggles to self-actualize in social and psychological settings that largely fails to accommodate his intelligence."
Here's the trailer: 


